# matlab: find position of element in mixed array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I've an array with the following structure:

```
{ 
  { 'attr1', { 'val1', 'val2', 'valn'} },
  { 'attr2', { 'val4' } },
  { 'attr3', { 'val5', 'val6', 'valn'} }
}
```

How can I check the index of the element of `attr2`, for example?

I've found [some questions](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/282950) about finding elements in array, but they are uniform arrays, not mixed ones like my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can use *strfind*. But as the given object is nested cells, it creates bit problem. How about the following approach?

```
str = { 
  { 'attr1', { 'val1', 'val2', 'valn'} },
  { 'attr2', { 'val4' } },
  { 'attr3', { 'val5', 'val6', 'valn'} }
} ;

str1 = [str{:}] ;
attrs = str1(1:2:end) ;    % pick the attributes alone 
idx = strfind(attrs, 'attr2');
idx = find(not(cellfun('isempty', idx)));

iwant = str{2}
```